# JS - How to autoresize textarea based on input text mirrored from other textarea input?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to achieve that textarea height is automatically adjusted based on length of text which is mirrored into in from input textarea. Can you please take a look where might be the issue? Thank you for your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/wshuni/vjwe39ah/93/

```
var titleInput = document.querySelector("#titleInput");
var bodyInput = document.querySelector("#bodyInput");
var title = document.querySelector("#title");
var body = document.querySelector("#body");

title.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);
body.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);
titleInput.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);
bodyInput.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);
             
function autosize(){
  var el = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    el.style.cssText = 'height:auto; padding:0';
    // for box-sizing other than "content-box" use:
    // el.style.cssText = '-moz-box-sizing:content-box';
    el.style.cssText = 'height:' + el.scrollHeight + 'px';
  },0);
}



var input = document.querySelector("#titleInput");
var mirror = document.querySelector("#title");
var bodyInput = document.querySelector("#bodyInput");
var bodyMirror = document.querySelector("#body");

input.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  mirror.innerText = event.target.value;
 
});

bodyInput.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  bodyMirror.innerText = event.target.value;
 
});
```

[explanation - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCFRZ.png)

Comment: The textarea element is not going to resize unless you instruct it to do it. Use the same event to measure the size of the input element and resize the textarea element to the same height.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting styles for `bodyMirror` textarea in the same function you use to resize `bodyInput` textarea.

```
var bodyMirror = document.querySelector("#body");

function autosize(){
  var el = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    el.style.cssText = 'height:auto; padding:0';
    el.style.cssText = 'height:' + el.scrollHeight + 'px';
    bodyMirror.style.cssText =  'height:auto; padding:0';
    bodyMirror.style.cssText =  'height:' + el.scrollHeight + 'px';
  },0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove fixed height in body class and update the height of mirrored text area just after text is copied.

```js
var titleInput = document.querySelector("#titleInput");
var bodyInput = document.querySelector("#bodyInput");

titleInput.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);
bodyInput.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);
             
function autosize(){
  var el = this;
    el.style.cssText = 'height:auto; padding:0';
    // for box-sizing other than "content-box" use:
    // el.style.cssText = '-moz-box-sizing:content-box';
    el.style.cssText = 'height:' + el.scrollHeight + 'px';
}



var input = document.querySelector("#titleInput");
var mirror = document.querySelector("#title");
var bodyInput = document.querySelector("#bodyInput");
var bodyMirror = document.querySelector("#body");

input.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  mirror.innerText = event.target.value;
  mirror.style.cssText = 'height:' + mirror.scrollHeight + 'px';
 
});

bodyInput.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  bodyMirror.innerText = event.target.value;
  bodyMirror.style.cssText = 'height:' + bodyMirror.scrollHeight + 'px';
});
```

```css
.frame {
width: 343px;
height: 114px;
background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
border-radius: 8px;
}



.title {
font-family: Inter-SemiBold;
position: relative;
font-size: 16px;
color: #21416C;
font-weight: 600;
height: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
width: 291px;
word-wrap: break-word;
border: none;
resize: none;
}

.body {
font-family: Inter-Regular;
position: relative;
font-size: 14px;
color: #5C7999;
font-weight: normal;
/*height: 16px;*/
line-height: 18px;
width: 311px;
word-wrap: break-word;
border: none;
resize: none;
}


.card {
  /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 343px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  height: auto;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.containerTitle {
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-right: 36px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.containerBody {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

i {
  color: #1A67D2;
  font-size: 24px !important; /* 24px preferred icon size */
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 78px;
  padding-left: 307px;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#1A67D2;">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
      

 <div class="containerTitle">
    <textarea id="titleInput" rows='1' type="text" class="title" placeholder="Add title text..."></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="containerBody">
    <textarea id="bodyInput" rows='1' type="text" class="body" placeholder="Add body text..."></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
  <div class="containerTitle">
    <textarea id="title" disabled rows='1' type="text" class="title" placeholder="Mirrored text - title..."></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="containerBody">
    <textarea id="body" disabled rows='1' type="text" class="body" placeholder="Mirrored text - body..."></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```